# rndc addzone failed: not found

Tags: dns, bind

I installed bin 9.8.4 (default) on Debian Wheezy.
after configuration I tried to add a slave zone with the following command:

```
rndc addzone test.zone '{ type slave; file "test.zone"; masters { ns.master; }; };'
```

the command failed with the response:

```
rndc: 'addzone' failed: not found
```

in the log file nothing was mentioned (even with debug log on). The last log lines are:

```
16-May-2014 21:32:31.002 general: debug 1: received control channel command 'null'
16-May-2014 21:32:31.002 general: info: received control channel command 'addzone test.zone { type slave; file "test.zone"; masters { ns.master; }; };'
```

the same thing already happens if I use the command:

```
rndc addzone test.zone '{};'
```

My questions are: What is wrong here and what do I need to change to make `rndc addzone` work?

Some additional information about my configuration setup:

`named.conf`

```
controls { inet 127.0.0.1 allow { localhost;}; };

include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options.global";

view "internal" {
    match-clients { internal; };

    include "/etc/bind/named.conf.zone.localhost";   // 127.0.0.*
    include "/etc/bind/named.conf.zone.internal";    // 192.168.*
    include "/etc/bind/named.conf.zone.local";       // external master zones
};

view "external" {
    match-clients { external; };

    include "/etc/bind/named.conf.zone.root";         // . hint
    include "/etc/bind/named.conf.zone.local";        // external master zones
};
```

`named.conf.options.global`

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    dnssec-validation auto;
    auth-nxdomain no;    # default no; conform to RFC1035
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
    allow-new-zones yes;
    allow-transfer { secondaryns; };
    allow-recursion { internal; };
    version none;
};
```

This is no `chroot` setup; I did not change `/etc/default/bind`;
ufw is setup, but ports 53 and 953 are open.

I did also run the `rndc addzone` command with a valid and existing subzone that is hosted on another name server (transfer on etc) with no different result.